# getting an empty response returned from nodeJS + Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I apologize if this does not follow the comunity standars, but please note I tried my best.

I'm having troubles returning a JSON response in my API which grabs content from a MongoDB instance

Basically I have the following file which handles the nodejs server (server.js):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Person = require('./models/people');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testdb');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var router = express.Router();

router.use(function (req,res,next) {
    console.log('something going on');
    next();
})

router.get('/', function (req,res) {
    res.status(500).json({
        error: 'unauthorized'
    });
});

router.route('/getPeople').get(function (req,res){
    Person.find(function (err,people) {
        console.log('err: ' , err);
        console.log('people: ' , people);
        if (err)
            res.send(err)
        res.json(people);
    })
})

app.use('/api',router);

app.listen(port);
console.log('server started on port : ' , port);
```

The model is as follows(people.js):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var PeopleSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    surname: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Person',PeopleSchema)
```

My DB is correctly filled with a value, and if I access it using mongo shell (db.People.find()) I get the correct result. Instead, using the code, it doesn't work.

Comment: What does your output show?

Comment: I mean your console log.  You see people: []?

Comment: Following the console.logs outputs:

err:  null
people:  []

Comment: I see nothing wrong with that code, so my guess is that there is either something else in the code that isn't shown here or your configuration is wrong.  My guess is the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the condition or search criteria object in the **[`find()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)** method, it's missing in your code. You only included the callback function. Try rewriting the routing method and changing your model name to reflect the database name as:

**people.js ('./models/people'):**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var PeopleSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    surname: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('People', PeopleSchema);
```

or should you wish to retain the model name as Person, you can pass the collectionName as the third argument in the **`model()`** function arguments:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Person', PeopleSchema, 'People');
```

or as a property in the schema definition:

```
var PeopleSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    surname: String
}, { collection: 'People' });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Person', PeopleSchema);
```

**server (server.js):**

```
/* if using the renamed People model */
router.route('/getPeople').get(function (req,res){
    People.find({}, function (err, people) {
        console.log('err: ' , err);
        console.log('people: ' , people);
        if (err)
            res.send(err)
        res.json(people);
    });
});
```

or via executing a query:

```
/* if using the renamed People model */
router.route('/getPeople').get(function (req,res){
    People.find().exec(function (err, people) {
        console.log('err: ' , err);
        console.log('people: ' , people);
        if (err)
            res.send(err)
        res.json(people);
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried both methods and it still returns an empty array ("[]"). Following the result of the query through mongo:

> db.People.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56ab23e9549c1fa6720e6b24"), "name" : "Luca", "surname" : "Digiusto" }
>

Comment: Try changing the model name or pass the collectionName as the third argument as per my update above.

Comment: Adding the CollectionName as third parameter did do the trick. But I'm not sure I understand why. Do you know what might it be?

Please note I was following this guide -> https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4

Comment: It's because MongoDB uses named collections of arbitrary objects and a Mongoose JS Model abstracts away this layer so that you don’t have to deal with tasks such as asynchronously telling MongoDB to switch to that collection. If this solved your problem consider [accepting the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), as with the norm around here. You may want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I see, thanks for the help. I've accepted this answer as it actually did fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just try

```
 Person.find()
   .exec(function (err, people) {
       console.log('err: ' , err);
       console.log('people: ' , people);
       if (err)
          res.send(err)
       res.json(people);
    })
```

This musst work if not is the error not in your route. //Edit yeah in your find is missing the condition you have passed the callback in the condition.

```
Person.find({},function (err,people) {
```